# console error Use of deprecated autoTable initiation

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Good morning, guys, I'm working on vue js with vuetify it turns out that when I put this to generate a pdf to print it through jspdf and autotable jspdf I get the following in console

this is my code in vue.js

```
createPdf() {
  var doc = new jsPDF()
  var rows =[];
  
  var columns= [
    { header: 'Code', dataKey: 'code' },
    { header: 'Name', dataKey: 'namearticle' },
    { header: 'Category', dataKey: 'category' },
  ];
  this.articles.map(function(x){
    rows.push({code:x.code,namearticle:x.namearticle,category:x.category});
  });
  doc.autoTable(columns,rows)
  doc.save("table.pdf");
}
```

this is in methods in vue.js but this code works, but this comes out in console
Use of deprecated autoTable initiation

Comment: I have no experience with jspdf, but have you tried using pdfmake?. I've been working with it since 2 years now and I really recommend it. http://pdfmake.org/#/

Answer (score 3):

Good morning, I have solved the old code issue as follows

```
createPdf() {
  var doc = new jsPDF()
  var rows =[];
  this.articles.map(function(x){
          rows.push({code:x.code,namearticle:x.namearticle,category:x.category,stock:x.stock,price_sale:x.price_sale,numberstatate:x.numberstatate ? 'Activate' : 'Inactivate'});
  });
  doc.autoTable({
    columns:[
      { header: 'Code', dataKey: 'code' },
      { header: 'Name', dataKey: 'namearticle' },
      { header: 'Category', dataKey: 'category' },
      { header: 'Stock', dataKey: 'stock' },
      { header: 'Price Sale', dataKey: 'price_sale' },
      { header: 'State', dataKey: 'numberstatate' },
    ],
    body:rows,
    margin:{top:35},
    didDrawPage:function(data){
    doc.text("TOLIST ARTICLES", 20, 30);
  }})
  doc.save("table.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really helpfull, i had something like:

```
array.forEach(element => Rows.push(
        element.Name));
```

And in my PDF i was seeing the first letter of "element.Name" instead of the full string. So i forget to map it correctly with the column.

```
array.forEach(element => Rows.push(
        {accountName:element.Name}));
```